# Why is my SQL table only showing one one row with null columns after I run this code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

```
const db = require('./db');
const { createHash } = require('crypto');

async function registerUser(user, pass, email) {
    if (pass.includes('?') || pass.includes('\'') || pass.includes('\"')) {
        return false;
    }

    const salt = makeSalt(16);
    console.log("salt: " + salt);
    var hash = salt.concat(pass);
    console.log("salt and pass: " + hash);
    hash = createHash('sha256').update(hash).digest('hex');
    console.log(hash);

    try {
        await db.query('INSERT INTO users (user, salt, hash, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [user, salt, hash, email]);
        console.log("User registered successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error registering user:", error);
    }
}

function makeSalt(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@!#$&_';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter < length) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}

// Example usage
registerUser("test", "spacefort66", "example@gmail.com");
```

I tried setting all database columns to different values (they are all currently set to VARCHAR), I am expecting a row with the user name, salt, hash, and then the email.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your output UI after the query is executed? That may help to understand your problem further and provide more details support from everyone.

Comment: Here are screenshots of the SQL Table and the console output:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/iL3nsPj)
@TrầnQuangSơn

Comment: That screenshot isn't showing a table with a single row and all null values, it is showing an empty table with an editor row in the UI where you can add a new row. Your table is empty, so based on the code showing has having run, it might indicate that you are inserting to a different server than you are checking for rows. Are you sure you are checking the right place?